# Проблема с dropdown-toggle внутри TD (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: css, bootstrap, dropdown, display

Приветствую.

Имеется Bootstarp 4.0.0-alpha.2 и следующей HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="list-inline-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Four</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Five</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Six</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Seven</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Eight</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Nine</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="">Dropdown</a></li>
</ul>

<br /><br />

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>Six</td>
        <td>Seven</td>
        <td><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="">Dropdown</a></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Следующий CSS:

```
.dropdown-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-right: .25rem;
    margin-left: .25rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: "";
    border-top: .3em solid;
    border-right: .3em solid transparent;
    border-left: .3em solid transparent;
}
```

И следующая проблема:

Когда ссылка с классом "dropdown-toggle" находится в DIV-е, SPAN-е или в списке, то при изменении размера окна ссылка переносится целиком вместе с "dropdown-toggle::after".

Но когда такая ссылка находтся в таблице, то при изменение размера окна "dropdown-toggle::after" съезжает вниз.

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы в таблице (TD) при изменении размера окна "dropdown-toggle::after" не съезжал вниз?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается добавлением следующего класса:

```
.dropdown-table {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Пример:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>Six</td>
        <td>Seven</td>
        <td><a class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-table" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="">Dropdown</a></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```